# Extract regex match from pandas column and use as index to access list element

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe that looks like this:

```
    col1    col2    col3
0  A,B,C     0|0     1|1
1  D,E,F     2|2     3|3
2  G,H,I     4|4     0|0
```

My goal is to apply a function on col2 through the last column of the dataframe that splits the corresponding string in col1, using the comma as the delimiter, and uses the first number as the index to get the corresponding list element. For numbers that are greater than the length of the list, I'd like to replace with the 0th element of the list.

Expected output:

```
    col1    col2    col3
0  A,B,C       A       B
1  D,E,F       F       D
2  G,H,I       G       G
```

In reality, my dataframe has thousands of columns with millions of entries that need this replacement, so I need a method that doesn't refer to 'col2' and 'col3' explicity (and preference for a computationally efficient method).

You can use this code to create the original dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
        {
                'col1': ['A,B,C', 'D,E,F', 'G,H,I'],
                'col2': ['0|0', '2|2', '4|4'],
                'col3': ['1|1', '3|3', '0|0']
        }
)
```

Comment: Is it guaranteed that the number on both sides of `|` are the same?

Comment: Yes, both numbers will always be the same.

Comment: do you have just col2 and col3 or do you have many more columns?

Comment: The ```0|0``` is a common format that many bioinformatics tools use to represent genotypes. So I'm receiving these files already formatted like that. And yes, there are thousands of columns in my dataframe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking into account that you could have a lot of columns and the length of the arrays in `col1` could vary, you can use the following generalization, which only loops through the columns:

```
for col in df.columns[1:]:
    df[col] = (df['col1']+','+df[col].str.split('|').str[0]).str.split(',') \
        .apply(lambda x: x[int(x[-1])] if int(x[-1]) < len(x[:-1]) else x[0])
```

which outputs for your example:

```
>>> print(df)

    col1 col2 col3
0  A,B,C    A    B
1  D,E,F    F    D
2  G,H,I    G    G
```

#### Explanation:

first you get the index as string from `colX` and append to the string in `col1` so that you get something like `'A,B,C,0'` and split it to get a list with the last element been the index that you need (`[A,B,C,0]`):

```
(df['col1']+','+df[col].str.split('|').str[0]).str.split(',')
```

Then you apply a function that returns the ith element been i the last element of the list and if i is bigger then the len of the list - 1 then return just the first element of the list.

```
(df['col1']+','+df[col].str.split('|').str[0]).str.split(',') \
    .apply(lambda x: x[int(x[-1])] if int(x[-1]) < len(x[:-1]) else x[0])
```

Last but not least, you just put it in a loop over your desired columns.

Comment: Wonderful :) And I really appreciate the thorough explanation. I upvoted, but I'm going to wait a bit before accepting in case someone comes along with another solution. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I would first reduce your strange `x|x for all x` format:

```
df['col2'] = df['col2'].str.split('|', expand=True).iloc[:, 0]
df['col3'] = df['col3'].str.split('|', expand=True).iloc[:, 0]
```

Then split the letter mappings while keeping them aligned by row.

```
ndf = pd.concat([df, df['col1'].str.split(',', expand=True)], axis=1)
```

After that, map them back by row while making sure to prevent overflows:

```
def bad_mapping(row, c):
    value = int(row[c])
    if value <= 2:  # adjust if needed
        return row[value]
    else:
        return row[0]

for c in ['col2', 'col3']:
    ndf['mapped_' + c] = ndf.apply(lambda r: bad_mapping(r, c), axis=1)
```

Output looks like:

```
    col1 col2 col3  0  1  2 mapped_col2 mapped_col3
0  A,B,C    0    1  A  B  C           A           B
1  D,E,F    2    3  D  E  F           F           D
2  G,H,I    4    0  G  H  I           G           G
```

Drop columns with `df.drop(columns=['your', 'columns', 'here'], inplace=True)` as needed.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, this solution would require me to loop through the entire dataframe twice. With millions of entries, I think this would be unnecessarily slow.

Comment: The way your data frame is set up, you want to run it in C or some other fast language. I don't believe there's any way not to hit a for-loop and start doing lookups. Pass the data in a formatted form to your C program and then execute for results. Then reload your data.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not familiar with C :(